# Force Video Autoplay Using Chrome Browser on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

While using a mobile device, video auto-play does not work on Chrome but it works on Firefox & Opera. (Not sure what the story is with Safari as I have no iOS device).

OPTION 1: Using video tag:

html code:

```
<video autoplay loop poster="images/bg.jpg" id="video_bg">
<source src="video.webm" type="video/webm">
<source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

css code:

```
video#video_bg {
position: fixed; right: 0; bottom: 0;
min-width: 100%; min-height: 100%;
width: auto; height: auto; z-index: -100;
background: url(../images/bg.jpg) no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
}
```

OPTION 2: Using YouTube embedded video code with auto-play set: (Again, works on a desktop but not on a mobile)

html code:

```
<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/xzvScRnF6MU?autoplay=1" width="960" height="447" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

My Question:

Is there any javascript code that would force auto-play on Chrome browser while viewing the page on a mobile device? Any other suggestions, please? Thank you!

Comment: AFAIK .. as of today June 2016.. Autoplay works on Chrome by default .. chk https://plus.google.com/+FrancoisBeaufort/posts/6PiJQqJzGqX

Answer (score 3):

Not really. For the same reason that mobile Safari and Chrome ignore the `autoplay` and `preload` attributes for `audio` and `video` tags, they also will *not* honor the `play()` or `load()` methods — or any method that would cause data activity on the network — for related entities unless they are called directly within user-interaction callback handlers. The reason is to prevent potentially costly data charges for users on cellular data. More information in [Apple's Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html).

Read [Overcoming iOS HTML5 audio limitations](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-ioshtml5/#N100D5) — a fantastic article that explains your exact situation and provides example solutions.

A hack I've used in the past is to place one of the valid "user-interaction" events (such as `onmousedown`, `onmouseup`, `onclick`, and `ontouchstart`) on a high-level element and initiate the data load in its callback. As an illustrative example, you could place an `ontouchstart` event on the `body` — which will be triggered whenever a user does *anything* on a page — to ensure the data begins loading as early as possible.

```
var body = document.getElementById('body');
var audio = document.getElementById('audio');

var loadData = function () {
    audio.load();
};

body.addEventListener('ontouchstart', loadData, false);
```

But the best solution will really depend on your use case. Always consider [audio sprites](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-ioshtml5/#audiosprites) as well and using a WebAudio framework, such as [HolwerJS](https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js/#define-and-play-a-sound-sprite), can really simplify your life!